# Print {1} in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, format, python-3.5

I want to get a printed output in Python 3.5 looking like `{1}` but I don't get the `.format` syntax right. I tried:

```
print('{{}}'.format('1'))        # prints {}
print('{{id}}'.format(id='1'))   # prints {id}
print('{{0}}'.format('1'))       # prints {0}
print('\{{}\}'.format(1))        # ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string
```

What is the right `print('{}'.format())` syntax to print something like `{1}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> print('{{{}}}'.format(1))
{1}
```

The innermost `{}` are used to insert the `1`. The outermost `{{` and `}}` are used to print the `{` and `}` but you need two of them to escape the `{` and `}` (as these are normally used for indicating places).

Answer (score 1):

```
print ('{' + format('1') + '}')
```